# use of addChild inside a function to add a child into a previously added instance

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, oop, adobe

I wrote a simple function "adone" to add things to the stage and today I decided to make it add child to other objects as well but the test function "ad2" I made is not working right. what do you suggest?

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class main extends MovieClip {
    public var ui:Array = new Array;
    public var splz:Array = new Array;
    public var pows:powsys = adone("powsz",powsys,ui,400,240);
    public var s1:powsyspsl = ad2("s1",powsyspsl,splz,100,100,"powsz");

    public function main() {

    }
    public function adone(nm,tp,lst,ex=0,ey=0) {
        nm = new tp();
        addChild(nm);
        lst.push(nm);
        nm.x = ex;
        nm.y = ey;
    }
    public function ad2(nm,tp,lst,ex=0,ey=0,par=null) {
        nm = new tp();
        par.addChild(nm);
        lst.push(nm);
        nm.x = ex;
        nm.y = ey;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public var pows:powsys = adone("powsz",powsys,ui,400,240);
```

you are setting first parameter `"powsz"` but you're not using this parameter, you're just changing it with `nm = new tp();` when your `adone()` function worked, so it is looking like working properly...

and here...

```
public var s1:powsyspsl = ad2("s1",powsyspsl,splz,100,100,"powsz");
```

you're not making the same fault as in "adone()" so it is still a string variable and you're trying to add a child to a string variable "powsz" here? i think you should fix that

```
par.addChild(nm);
```

but if you don't wanna fix things but you wanna your code work unproperly you can try this

```
public function ad2(nm,tp,lst,ex=0,ey=0,par=null) {
        nm = new tp();
        par = new tp();
        par.addChild(nm);
        lst.push(nm);
        nm.x = ex;
        nm.y = ey;
    }
```

And all this stuff looks like a joke! Your problems not going to be solved by this way, you have to fix your whole code and logic.. You're using lots of unnecessary stuff and wrong ways to make what you want...

Comment: yes my intention is to figure out the right way to do things like this. in fact I'll delete 2nd function as soon as I figure out how the things work and do them all with one function.
------- first I've done "public var pows:powsys = adone("pows",powsys,ui,400,240);" but it gave me errors and I felt like I'm trying to addChild to a variable not the object itself.----- now what do you suggest as the best way?

Comment: ow and I forgot to mention that I will add an "if" part to make the parent option optional.

Comment: you should use this "powsyspsl" in your "ad2(nm,tp,lst,ex=0,ey=0,par=null)" function's "par" section. Also you don't need "par = new tp();" in your ad2, so it is not doing anything already..

Comment: I taught that It's necessary (kind of) to make a new instance of a class before using it.

Comment: sorry, i mean "powsys" instead of "powsyspsl" ==> ad2(nm,tp,lst,ex=0,ey=0,toHERE)

Comment: if you mean to put the type in the function input like "function adone(nm,tp,lst,ex=0,ey=0,par:powsyspsl=null)" this will defeat the purpose of having an function for all adding I would need. or am I not getting what you mean at all?

Answer (score 1):

changed the code to:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class main extends MovieClip {
    public var ui:Array = new Array  ;
    public var splz:Array = new Array  ;
    public var pows:powsys = adone("pows",powsys,ui,400,240);
    public var s1:powsyspsl = adone("s1",powsyspsl,splz,100,100,pows);

    public function main() {

    }
    public function adone(nm,tp,lst,ex=0,ey=0,par=null) {
        nm = new tp  ;
        if (par) {
            par.addChild(nm);
        } else {
            addChild(nm);
        }
        lst.push(nm);
        nm.x = ex;
        nm.y = ey;
    }
}
}
```

the "par" var returns null both times in the trace. and that means 2nd object is added to the stage not to 1st one.

Comment: oh man, you've serious problems, wait, i'll fix your whole code.

Comment: thanks ^_^. btw it's more like experimenting and learning. I know its almost the same amount of the code if I do this the old fashion way.

Answer (score 1):

Untested....

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class main extends MovieClip {
    public var ui:Array = new Array;
    public var splz:Array = new Array;
    public var pows:powsys = adone(powsys,ui,400,240);
    public var s1:powsyspsl = adone(powsyspsl,ui,400,240,pows);

    public function main() {

    }
    public function adone(tp,lst,ex=0,ey=0,par=null):Object {
        var nm = new tp();
        if (par) {
            par.addChild(nm);
        } else {
            addChild(nm);
        }
        lst.push(nm);
        nm.x = ex;
        nm.y = ey;
        return nm;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think I got it ^_^. since the var name is defined I dont have to give each object a name again. am I right?

Comment: but the problem is still there. both time par returns null and s1 is not added to pows as a child.

Comment: you're right, also a word can have different data type.

i mean, this ==> >pows< is not a string, it is an >powsys< object here. but this >"pows"< is a string, it is not object, and you cannot reach an object by a string unless you use `flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;` feature. it should be look like this if you wanna reach an object by a string.  

`public var s1:powsyspsl = adone(powsyspsl,ui,400,240,getDefinitionByName("pows"));`

Comment: Your adone function have no return value, add a return value to it.

`public function adone(tp,lst,ex=0,ey=0,par=null):Object {
        var nm = new tp();
        if (par) {
            par.addChild(nm);
        } else {
            addChild(nm);
        }
        lst.push(nm);
        nm.x = ex;
        nm.y = ey;
return nm;
    }`